# Using AWS CodeStar Python project with JetBrain PyCharm

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pycharm, aws-codestar

I'm in the middle of evaluating CodeStar for some python programming on Amazon Lambda functions and have historically used [JetBrain PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) for my Python development. Eclipse and Visual Studio integration are mentioned directly in the [AWS CodeStar User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codestar/latest/userguide/setting-up-ide.html). I'm looking to try the Eclipse integration with PyCharm. PyCharm has import capabilities for Eclipse projects and Git integration that I've used in the past successfully.

Has anyone gotten this to work or have recommendations to share? I am using the full Professional Edition under a graduate student license but also have access to the free edition. I'll be trying it out and report back my findings.

Comment: I was unable to get it working with my brief testing but it feels like it should be possible if I just kept messing with it.

Comment: Have you ever find the solution to use PyCharm IDE for the development of AWS CodeStar? If yes, please share the steps which you followed to do this. It's very precious.

Comment: Nope, I never got it to work. I think about revisiting it occasionally but have moved on to using Serverless https://serverless.com/framework/ for what I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

Using PyCharm as your IDE for CodeStar in general is very doable.

A majority of the Codestar stack is IDE-independent. Regardless of which IDE you use, the core process will be that you will push to your git repo, and this triggers actions in a pipeline which builds and deploys that code to your host(s).

In PyCharm, you should be able to go to VCS > Checkout from version control > git, and clone from your CodeCommit repo. This link shows you how to setup your git credentials so that you can actually log in:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html?icmpid=docs_acc_console_connect_np

You can then code/test locally, then commit and push as usual when done, triggering that pipeline to build/deploy.

The AWS toolkit that's available for Eclipse/Visual Studio adds more features for interfacing with AWS, but CodeStar is designed to automate most of that for you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Toolkit for IntelliJ has been generally available since March 2019